# SQL Agent Job Set Values Disappeared When Migrating

Tags: sql-agent-job

When migrating a SQL Agent job from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016, the Set values tab in the Job Step Properties disappeared.  How are SQL Agent values passed to the SSIS packages in newer versions? Before, in the Set values tab, Package variable Property Paths were used to pass Package variable values that could be changed as needed.

[Old SQL Agent job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFBsD.png)

[New SQL Agent job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqzaD.png)